# conditional referencing of Python packages: UnboundLocalError

Tags: python

I would like to use function of same name from different packages dependent on a function flag:

```
import chainer.functions as F
def random_q_z(input, test = False):
    if test:
        F = np
        # ...
    else:
        # ...
        pass

    return F.sum(input)
```

However the interpreter protests:

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'F' referenced before assignment`

How to please it and do conditional referencing of packages?

---

I see that this question relates to other questions on variable scopes, but here the question is about how to handle different scopes. And the answer I got is valuable for this particular question.

Comment: I don't get what `F = np` is supposed to do but that line is the problem. If you have a read-only variable in a function (it just uses the value from a higher scope), you can do this. However, _reassigning_ it in the function body makes it a local, and since it's called regardless but only defined (locally) in the `if` branch, you get this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `F` a default parameter:

```
import chainer.functions as F

def random_q_z(input, test=False, F=F):
    if test:
        F = np

    return F.sum(input)
```

If you don't provide `F` as an argument when calling `random_q_z`, `chainer.functions` is used. You can also give `random_q_z` a different function for `F`.